# disabling the bootstraps according clickable element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i need to disable that i can click on the headers of the accordings to open. it should only be possible to open the next ones with an click on the "Next" Buttons. here is an example http://bootply.com/63398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the href property, either in the markup or with javascript :

```
$('.accordion-toggle').prop('href','#');
```